# Problema com lógica de média ponderada

Tags: java, algoritmo

Segundo todas as fontes que consultei, várias para ter certeza, a média ponderada é calculada da seguinte maneira:

Somam-se todos os valores que possuem o mesmo peso, depois multiplica-se esse somatório pelo referido peso. Faz-se isso para todos os valores e pesos diferentes. Depois soma-se esses resultados e divide-se pelo total de pesos somados.

Pois bem, criei um algoritmo em java que calcula a média ponderada desta maneira, porém, o resultado era sempre o dobro do esperado. Se deveria ser 3.8, ele gerava 7.6, se era 4.1 ele retornava 8.2. Não consigo encontrar onde estou multiplicando por 2 para ter esse resultado dobrado.

Creio que eu tenha feito a lógica correta, já reescrevi de diversas maneiras diferentes, mas sempre o mesmo erro. Resolvi dividindo o resultado por 2 antes de printar, mas queria entender o porquê do meu alg estar fazendo isto.

```
public void mediaPonderada(int x) {
    ArrayList<Double> z = new ArrayList(gera(x));
    double peso_1 = 0;
    double peso_2 = 0;
    double soma_1 = 0;
    double soma_2 = 0;

    System.out.printf("Informe o peso do primeiro grupo de valores: ");
    peso_1 = ler.nextDouble();
    System.out.printf("Informe o peso do segundo grupo de valores: ");
    peso_2 = ler.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("\nValores: ");
    System.out.println("Grupo 1: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < (z.size() / 2); i++) {
        System.out.println(df.format(z.get(i)));
        soma_1 += z.get(i);
    }
    soma_1 *= peso_1;

    System.out.println("\nGrupo 2: \n");
    for (int i = (z.size() / 2); i < (z.size()); i++) {
        System.out.println(df.format(z.get(i)));
        soma_2 += z.get(i);
    }
    soma_2 *= peso_2;
    System.out.println("\nMédia Ponderada equivale a: " + df.format(((soma_1 + soma_2) / (peso_1 + peso_2))));
}
```

Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
System.out.println("\nMédia Ponderada equivale a: " + df.format(((soma_1 + soma_2) / (peso_1 + peso_2))/2));
```

Comment: Mais simples (imho) , soma-se os pesos , multiplica-se todos os pares peso x valores e se acumula um total , divide-se este total pela soma dos pesos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lógica está parcialmente correta.

Eu francamente prefiro multiplicar todos os pesos já em decimais.

O erro na lógica está aqui:

```
df.format(((soma_1 + soma_2) / (peso_1 + peso_2)))
```

Deve-se, impreterivelmente, dividir pelo total de pesos aplicados, não somente os grupos.
[image: Média Ponderada]

No caso, ficaria algo do tipo:

```
 df.format(((soma_1 + soma_2) / ((peso_1 + peso_2)*z.size()/2)))
```

No caso, coloca-se o z.size()/2 em evidencia para ambos os termos, e multiplica-se o total dos pesos somados.

PS: sua solução de dividir por dois, somente funciona em uma ArrayList de 4 elementos, para 6, você teria que dividir por 3, e por assim subsequente.

Tome muito cuidado com esses remendos de código, não costumam funcionar.